# Why does uniq return an illogical answer when used inside another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Thank you for your time. I have an interesting logical error in my RSpec specification. Below I have provided two examples, the first one always fails whilst the second passes.

For example: The below code will create a failing specification expecting 3 but getting back 1

```
it "must not have the same question twice" do
  exam = Exam.new
  q1 = Question.new(question: "What color is the sky?")
  q2 = Question.new(question: "What color is the sky?")
  q3 = Question.new(question: "What sound does a dog make?")
  q4 = Question.new(question: "What sound does a dog make?")
  q5 = Question.new(question: "hello world?")
  exam.questions.push(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5)
  expect(exam.questions.uniq.size).to eql(3)
end
```

However when I use the below, replacing the Exam object with a regular array it works as intended and passes the specification.

```
it "must not have the same question twice" do
  exam = []
  q1 = Question.new(question: "What color is the sky?")
  q2 = Question.new(question: "What color is the sky?")
  q3 = Question.new(question: "What sound does a dog make?")
  q4 = Question.new(question: "What sound does a dog make?")
  q5 = Question.new(question: "hello world?")
  exam.push(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5)
  expect(exam.uniq.size).to eql(3)
end
```

Here is a sample of my overrode methods inside my question object

```
def ==(other)
  question == other.question
end

def eql?(other)
  other.is_a?(self.class) && question.eql?(other.question)
end

def hash
  question.hash
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exam.questions.uniq` is removing duplicates for an ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.

`exam.uniq` is removing duplicates for an Array.

If you look at the ActiveRecord [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb) you can see that record ID is used to determine uniqueness instead of equality.

```
  def distinct
    seen = {}
    load_target.find_all do |record|
      seen[record.id] = true unless seen.key?(record.id)
    end
  end
  alias uniq distinct
```

Comment: Ah, good catch! I think my logic is flawed in my design. I may need to go back to the drawing board on this one.